# Eating fish and meat together

Tags: food, meat, fish, health-safety-shmira

The reason given for not eating fish and meat together is due to Sakana. In current times it does not seem to be a Sakana, (Nishtanu HaTeva). Would you be allowed to eat them together? If not - why not / If yes - why yes?

Comment: IIRC the Rambam brings it down nowhere, and I've heard speculated that its for this very reason

Comment: an interesting note is I have seen on packages of frozen meat that the fda suggests not cooking raw beef and raw fish together

Comment: @Dude Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: @DoubleAA "[Use one cutting board for fresh produce and a separate one for raw meat, poultry, and seafood.](https://www.fda.gov/food/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm255180.htm)"

Comment: @Ploni they don't recommend splitting meat and seafood

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the discussion here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/things-we-do-not-do-because-of-danger/2264#2264).  The Magen Avraham shrugs his shoulders as to why this prohibition became carved-in-stone halacha, but once it did, we accept it as such.

Comment: @Shalom I wholeheartedly disagree with your reading of the Magen Avraham as do i think the Mishna Berurah and Aruch Hashulchan did. My Rosh Yeshiva certainly did when I discussed it with him. What he added was that nowadays since people are definitely stringent, one should worry that the Teva changed back, or that in these places it never changed, which is what the Aruch Hashulchan might actually be saying. But the Magen Avraham was not saying to be machmir, he was saying one can be lenient and they can be eaten together.

Comment: @user6591 that's the way R' Schachter shlit'a reads the Magen Avraham as well: he's actually arguing and saying it's permitted. Many, though, still don't actually do it. Someone asked Rabbi Schacter at the practical level if he'd eat them together: *"well, my wife wouldn't serve them together!"* "Okay Rav Schachter, if you came to my house and we were serving fish-and-meat, would you eat it?" *"Well, I should ..."*

Comment: @Shalom I think anyone I've shown the Magen Avraham/Mishna Berura to had never seen it. That's where the 'minhag' comes from:) But where are you quoting your reading of the M.A.? From the fact that people are still makpid? Not that you care what user6591 does but as of yet I've never had the Tayva for fish n' meat, but i have definitely used the same plate for both by kidushim and don't mind the meat sauces with anchovies, no tzaraas yet!!

Comment: But then again, there is a flaw in the test called lashon hara. Don't know what to do about that. But don't you with we would care as much about that kasha lidavar acher as the fish and meat one?!

Answer (score 2):

[Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/fish-and-meat.html) brings some sources for this debate and points out interestingly that while it is mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch, there is no mention of this in Rambam:

> The Mishna Berura (173:3) and Aruch Hashulchan (YD 116:10) quote the Magen Avraham (OC 173:1) who writes that this is one of many natural phenomena mentioned in the Gemara that no longer apply. The Chasam Sofer (YD 101) suggests that this may be why there is no mention of this in Rambam.
>
> Nonetheless, the Chasam Sofer concedes with the majority of poskim (Chochmas Adam 68:1; Maharam Shick YD 244; Kaf Hachaim OC 173:9), who write that this prohibition still applies even if we don’t understand the danger (See Yad Ephraim 116:3).