# Cholim she'yesh bahem sakanah

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, age, choleh-sick, baby-infant

Are there rabbinical sources on what qualifies someone as a *choleh she'yesh bo sakanah* - a sick person whose life is in danger?

Is it strictly a medical decision?  Are there circumstances in which our tradition may consider someone sakanah where the medical community doesn't?  Does extreme youth factor into it so that someone's drawn a line (e.g., sick children under one year old are always she'yesh bahem sakanah)?

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes, we find cases in halacha where a person is considered in danger, even though medically we see no reason for it.

The details are discussed in Shulchan Aruch. You can find a synopsis in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch.

For example,  in סימן צב - דין חולה שיש בו סכנה we find:

> סעיף ד' 
>   כָּל מַכָּה שֶׁבִּפְנִים הַגּוּף, דְּהַיְנוּ מִן הַשָּׂפָה וְלִפְנִים וְגַם הַשִּׁנַיִם בִּכְלָל, וְהַיְנוּ קִלְקוּל שֶׁמֵּחֲמַת מַכָּה אוֹ בוּעָה וְכַיוֹצֵא בָזֶה, מְחַלְּלִין עָלָיו אֶת הַשַׁבָּת וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ אֹמֶד, שֶׁאֲפִלּוּ אֵין שָׁם בְּקִיאִים וְחוֹלֶה אֵינוֹ אוֹמֵר כְּלוּם, עוֹשִׂין לוֹ כָּל מַה שֶּׁרְגִילִים לַעֲשׂוֹת בְּחֹל. אֲבָל כְּשֶׁיוֹדְעִים וּמַכִּירִים בְּאוֹתוֹ חֳלִי שֶׁמַּמְתִּין וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְחִלּוּל שַׁבָּת אֵין מְחַלְּלִין. מֵחוּשִׁים אֵינָן נִקְרָאִין מַכָּה. וּמִי שֶַׁחוֹשֵׁשׁ בְּשִׁנּוֹ וּמִצְטַעֵר עָלֶיהָ מְאֹד עַד שֶׁחָלָה מִמֶּנָּהּ כָּל גּוּפוֹ, מֻתָּר לוֹמַר לְאֵינוֹ יְהוּדִי שֶׁיּוֹצִיאָהּ.

Any wound or blister from the lips and inwards - including teeth - is considered a danger to one's health, unless one knows for a fact that treatment can safely wait until after Shabbat.

> סעיף ה' 
>   מַכָּה שֶׁעַל גַּב הַיָּד וְשֶׁעַל גַּב הָרֶגֶל, וְכֵן עַל כָּל מַכָּה שֶׁנֶּעֶשְֹתָה מֵחֲמַת בַּרְזֶל, וְעַל שְׁחִין שֶׁבְּפִי הַטַּבַּעַת, וְכֵן מִי שֶׁבָּלַע עֲלוּקָה אוֹ שֶׁנְּשָׁכוֹ כֶּלֶב שׁוֹטֶה אוֹ אֶחָד מִזּוֹחֲלֵי עָפָר, אֲפִלּוּ סָפֵק אִם מֵמִית אִם לָאו, וְכֵן מִי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ קַדַּחַת חָזָק בְּיוֹתֵר, מְחַלְּלִין עָלָיו אֶת הַשַׁבָּת. אֲבָל עַל קַדַּחַת הַמְּצוּיָה, אֵין מְחַלְּלִין, אֶלָּא עוֹשִׂין עַל יְדֵי אֵינוֹ יְהוּדִי.

Wounds on the back of the hand and top of the foot, or any wound from metal objects..., dog bites, retile bites, fever...

> סעיף ו' 
>   מִי שֶׁאֲחָזוֹ דָּם, מַקִּיזִין אוֹתוֹ מִיָּד. וְכָל שֶׁהִקִּיז דָּם וְנִצְטַנֵּן, עוֹשִׂין לוֹ מְדוּרָה לְהִתְחַמֵּם אֲפִלּוּ בִּתְקוּפַת תַּמּוּז.

Bloodletting... chills after blood letting...

> סעיף ז' 
>   הַחוֹשֵׁשׁ בִּשְׁתֵּי עֵינָיו אוֹ שֶׁהָיָה בְּאַחַת מֵהֵן צִיר אוֹ שֶׁהָיוּ שׁוֹתְתוֹת אוֹ שֶׁהָיָה דָּם שׁוֹתוֹת אוֹ שְׁאָר דָּבָר שֶׁהוּא סַכָּנָה לָעַיִן, מְחַלְּלִין עָלָיו אֶת הַשַׁבָּת.

Wounds in the eyes...

In סימן צג - דיני יולדת  we find that once labour starts, the expect mother is considered to be in danger.

In סימן ד - הנהגת בית הכסא we find that one may urinate in public, is it's dangerous to keep it in.

In סִימָן לג - דְּבָרִים הָאֲסוּרִים מִשּׁוּם סַכָּנָה we find the danger of eating fish with meat.

Ibid: A person who smells food and craves it is in danger if he doesn't get to taste some.

Ibid: Cutting down fruit tress is considered dangerous.

In סִימָן צג - דִּינֵי יוֹלֶדֶת - Mothers after childbirth are considered to be in danger for the first 3 days; and for some halachot for the first 7 days.

In סִימָן קסא - דִּינֵי חֲצִיצָה we find it's dangerous to cut off "dreadlocks?" `קליעות שערות דבוקות זו בזו, שקורין בלשון אשכנז מאהר-צעפ או מאר-לאקען, ובלשון פולין ורוסיא קאלטניס`

In סִימָן צ - דִּין עֲשִֹיַת חֲפָצָיו בְּלִא מְלָאכָה - all are in danger when it comes to cold weather.

- A baby on its 3rd day (or up to 3 days) after a Brit Mila is in danger.

Comment: But are these halakha that moderns care about l'maaseh?  Certainly not "dreadlocks", i.e., Polish plait.  On that, see [this conversation from 2.5 years ago on that topic](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/things-we-do-not-do-because-of-danger/2259#comment2233_2259) with some folks you might know.

Comment: True - but you asked "Are there circumstances in which our tradition may consider someone sakanah where the medical community doesn't?" and I think we can answer YES to that.