# What was the "danger" of concern that prohibited eating fish with meat?

Tags: halacha, meat, fish

This M.Y. answer lists a prohibition of eating [fish and meat together](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2259/5275) because of *sakana* - it was dangerous.

What was the danger at the time this prohibition was instituted?

Comment: I once heard from a guy who told me he heard from his Rabbi that danger is because meat has only big bones, while fish have small bones. When eating the two together, you may be less careful with the fish bones, and you may end up choking on the fish bones. -- This is a very rationalistic explanation (not like the talmud quoted in one of the answers below). I have no idea what the actual source is.

Answer (score 2):

It can cause leprosy. I heard this at a shiur (if I recall correctly, given by Rabbi Michoel Stern), but I found this online:
http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/ask-the-expert-meat-and-fish/

Edit: Pesachim 76b

> A fish was roasted [i.e., baked] together with meat,
>   [whereupon] Raba of Parzikia forbade it to be eaten with kutah. Mar b. R. Ashi said: Even with salt
>   too it is forbidden, because it is harmful to [one's] smell and in respect of ‘something else'.

Rashi explains 'something else' as tzora'as (i.e. leprosy).

Comment: Tzora'as != leprosy

Comment: FWIW SA YD 116:2 agrees with this interpretation.